# How to retrieve Query string from URL and recreate the complete URL

Tags: java, http, url, servlets

I know the query string is a part of the URL and followed by the "?" separation character. 
I am going through an example code. I do not understand the purpose of this line of code -

```
String urlString = request.getRequestURL().toString();
String queryString = request.getQueryString();

urlString += queryString == null ? "" : "?" + queryString; 
// HOWS DOES THIS APPEND THE URL AND QUERY TO GENERATE URL. AND WHAT IS IT COMPARING TO NULL?
```

URL url = new URL(urlString);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the java ternary operator (sometimes called elvis operator ?:). The semantics is as follows:

```
bool ? A : B
```

is the same as

```
if (bool) A
else B
```

In you case:

```
urlString += (queryString == null ? "" : "?") + queryString;
```

will append the `queryString` to the `urlString` only if the `queryString` is not equal to `null` (it will append " " otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

The query string may not be present (i.e. null), and in that case, the code takes care to not append the "?". Reformatted:

```
urlString += (  (queryString == null) ? " " : ("?"+queryString)  );
```

Comment: And if the queryString was blindly appended without being checked for null it would append a String literal of "null".

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't know the ternary operator, which is `(if) ? (then) : (else)`

In your case `if (queryString != null) then ("") else ("?" + queryString)`

The code in the question is missing a parenthesis too as it should be this:

```
urlString += queryString == null ? "" : ("?" + queryString);
```